# Load a tensorflow model in java

Tags: java, python, tensorflow

I am trying to load a tensorflow model in Java.

```
tf.saved_model.simple_save(
                        sess,
                        "/tmp/model/"+timestamp,
                        inputs={"input_x" : cnn.input_x},
                        outputs={"input_y" : cnn.input_y})
```

This is how I save a tensorflow model in python.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        // good idea to print the version number, 1.2.0 as of this writing
        System.out.println(TensorFlow.version());        
        final int NUM_PREDICTIONS = 1;
            Random r = new Random();
            long[] shape = new long[] {1,56};
            IntBuffer buf = IntBuffer.allocate(1*56);
            for (int i = 0; i < 56; i++) {
               buf.put(r.nextInt());
            }
            buf.flip();


        // load the model Bundle
        try (SavedModelBundle b = SavedModelBundle.load("/tmp/model/1549001254", "serve")) {

        Session sess = b.session();

         // run the model and get the result, 4.0f.
                try(Tensor x = Tensor.create(shape, buf)){
           float[] result = sess.runner()
             .feed("input_x", x)
             .fetch("input_y")
             .run()
             .get(0)
                     .copyTo(new float[1][2])[0];

           // print out the result.
           System.out.println(result[0]);
                }

        }                
    }
```

This is how I load it in Java.

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  inputs['input_x'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_INT32
      shape: (-1, 56)
      name: input_x:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
  outputs['input_y'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, 2)
      name: input_y:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

The input and output are saved well.

```
1.12.0
2019-02-01 15:58:59.065677: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:31] Reading SavedModel from: /tmp/model/1549001254
2019-02-01 15:58:59.072601: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:54] Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
2019-02-01 15:58:59.085912: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2
2019-02-01 15:58:59.132271: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:162] Restoring SavedModel bundle.
2019-02-01 15:58:59.199331: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:138] Running MainOp with key legacy_init_op on SavedModel bundle.
2019-02-01 15:58:59.199435: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:259] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: success. Took 133774 microseconds.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_y' with dtype float and shape [?,2]
     [[{{node input_y}} = Placeholder[_output_shapes=[[?,2]], dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,2], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
    at org.tensorflow.Session.run(Native Method)
    at org.tensorflow.Session.access$100(Session.java:48)
    at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.runHelper(Session.java:314)
    at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.run(Session.java:264)
    at Use_model.main(Use_model.java:38)
```

But It cannot load the model... The error message is like this.

I don't know what is the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: Please do not use screen shots. Instead copy&paste the text to your question as code blocks or quote block, thank you.

Comment: Thank you Stefan, I edited my question:)

Answer (score 0):

There is some confusion about input_y in your code. The exception says:

```
You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_y' with dtype float and shape [?,2]
```

This means that, in your python code, input_y is defined to be a placeholder. I guess this is the placeholder that contains labels of the input_x items. Then input_y should be used in your loss function to compare the last layer of your cnn (let's call it cnn.output) with the actual labels (cnn.input_y), e.g.:

```
loss = tf.square(cnn.input_y - cnn.output)
```

Then, you python code should save cnn.output in the outputs dictionary, and not cnn.input_y:

```
tf.saved_model.simple_save(
                    sess,
                    "/tmp/model/"+timestamp,
                    inputs={"input_x" : cnn.input_x},
                    outputs={"output" : cnn.output})
```

In your java code you should then fetch "output":

```
float[] result = sess.runner()
         .feed("input_x", x)
         .fetch("output")
         .run()
         .get(0)
                 .copyTo(new float[1][2])[0];
```